# Dynamic method name generation using xmlrpc

Tags: python, xmlrpclib

How using Python I can dynamically generate my call to my xmlrpc server using `xmlrpc` lib?
something like

```
def call_method(method_name)
   server = Server(self.URL, transport=ProxiedTransport())
   server.method_name(params)
```

The resolution takes `method_name` instead of for example if `method_name=get_time`:
`server.get_time(params)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of `xmlrpclib` contains this comment, which you might find applicable outside its original context.

```
   # note: to call a remote object with an non-standard name, use
   # result getattr(server, "strange-python-name")(args)
```

It's a [general Python idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-from-a-string-with-the-functions-name-in-python).

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks I closed it.